# Selecting matches from Pockets

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling

If a man has 37 matches in the box in his left pocket and 21 in
the box in his right pocket and repeatedly grabs either box at
random to take a match out, what is the probability that he gets
to a point where he has one match in each pocket?

Is this a Binomial Dist and ans is $\frac{56C_2}{2^{56}}$?

Comment: Did you mean $_{56}C_{20}$?  That would be correct.  I don't know where you get $_{56}C_2$

Comment: yes i got it. It is 56C20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the first $56$ matches he reaches for.  We have success if and only if he reaches for the right pocket $20$ times and the left $36$ times.  So we have a string of $56$ letters each L or R with equal probability and we want the probability that exactly $20$ of them are R.

The answer is $$2^{-56}{56\choose20}$$